# conditional simulation(path dependent simulation) in R

Tags: r, simulation, iteration

My codes are not good, I want to konw how to solve my problem efficicently and learn writing some elegant R codes.Thanks in advance!

"r" is the starting value in `matrix[loop,T]`, I want to use it to do the simulation for 45years in 10 times,which means that I will get a new `matrix[loop,T]` also name "r" after first for-loop.Then, I want to use the second column data in this new matrix "r" to do the simulation again,which means that I will use `r[1,2],r[2,2],r[3,2]...r[loop,2]` to do the simulation, in this way,each data in r[,2] will create a matrix name "b"`[loop,T]`,so I compute the average value of the second column in each matrix "b"`[loop,T]`, then I get 10(=loop) new starting values again to do the simulation.At last,I have the final_data output

```
alpha<-0.0212;beta<-0.0063;sigma<-0.0012;dt<-1;T<-46;loop<-10
r<-matrix(rep(-0.0002,loop*T),loop,T)

for(i in 1:loop)
{
  for(j in 2:T)
  {
    r[i,j]<-r[i,j-1]+alpha*(beta-r[i,j-1])*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1,0,1)
  }

}

c<-matrix(rep(0,loop*1),loop,1)
for(k in 1:loop)
{
b<-matrix(rep(r[k,2],loop*T),loop,T)
for(i in 1:loop)
{
  for(j in 2:T)
  {
    b[i,j]<-b[i,j-1]+alpha*(beta-b[i,j-1])*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1,0,1)
  }
}
c[k,1]<-mean(b[,2])
}

e<-matrix(rep(0,loop*1),loop,1)
for(k in 1:loop)
{
  d<-matrix(rep(c[k,1],loop*T),loop,T)
  for(i in 1:loop)
  {
    for(j in 2:T)
    {
      d[i,j]<-d[i,j-1]+alpha*(beta-d[i,j-1])*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1,0,1)
    }
  }
  e[k,1]<-mean(d[,2])
}

final_data<-data.frame(r[,2],c,e)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to simulate?